# Which is more efficient in Ruby, Hash vs Array

Tags: arrays, ruby, hashmap

I am learning Ruby through the canonical [pickaxe book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1937785491).
In Section 2.3 of that book, I came across a sentence saying that,

> It’s more efficient to access array elements, but hashes provide more flexibility

As I understand, accessing array elements and looking up hash values by key both take O(1) time.

What does the author mean, when he says that arrays are more efficient for access? Does it simply mean that array is more efficient, because the internal representation of an array is simpler than a hash?

Comment: In essence, yes. Although the time complexity is the same, for an array it's really just an index in bounds check and then a multiplication. Hash tables have to do a lot more in that individual step.

Comment: In addition to the answers you'll get below, make sure to consider your use cases. If you're not dealing with many multiple iterations over large data sets, then it's likely that you won't notice a performance difference. In that case, let the model suggest the correct structure. Are you storing discrete, sequential items? Use an Array. Are you storing items by arbitrary key values? Use a Hash. Are you storing unique items where you don't care about the order? Use a Set. And so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does it simply mean that array is more efficient, because the internal representation of an array is simpler than a hash?

Yes. The algorithmic complexity may be the same, but an array is going to be faster generally, because the lookup procedure is much simpler. On the other hand when using an array the "keys" (indices) can only be integers, and an array is not sparse - if you store to `a[100]`, there will be at least 101 elements in the array afterwards.

(For extremely sparse arrays, a hash map should actually perform better).